# Network node highlighting with Crossfilter

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I have a graph with a network and a few histograms.

For the network, each node has a few properties with continuous value. The histograms are for node properties. Is there an easy way to highlight the node in the network, when users brush the histogram? Could I bind a dimension of the network data to the node class attribute "selectednode"?

I have checked dc.js, but it seems not support network graph.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Crossfilter isn't really built for highlighting, as filtering will remove the data outside the filter from the view of other dimensions and groups. It sounds like you don't want unselected network nodes to disappear, but rather want nodes with property values falling within the selection to be highlighted. I'd build either your histogram or your network directly based on unfiltered data (not based on the Crossfilter) and then whenever the brush event happens, re-render the network nodes, checking the current brush extent against the property values.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan Jewett, I also need to brush on the network, then I have to add brush functions on network for rendering histogram also.

Comment: The other option would be to drive the histogram and network off of Crossfilter but not have the brush on the histogram filter the Crossfilter. Just use it's extent values to highlight. Or you could have multiple brushes - one to filter the Crossfilter and one to highlight. Sorry, I'm kind of thinking through the options out-loud as I need to address the same issue on a project of mine.

Comment: Yes, I am working on a similar question. User can brush network to see the histogram(multi). User brushes the histogram, the highlight in brush region of the network will be changed. I am thinking to use dimension.filterFunction with brush.extent in my network brush function, and re-highlight the network in my histogram brush function. Just feel such design is highly coupled and not very good for extension.

Comment: Using event handlers to catch the brush events may be a way to make it a bit less highly coupled.

Comment: The solution provided can work for one property. But, when I have multiple properties and brush on multiple properties, the brush doesn't have all the previous brushing information. And, the highlighting will only have info for the last brushing property.

Comment: Are you using the same brush for all these properties? If you're using different brushes, I would expect each brush to maintain its own extent and you'll have to check all of them.

Comment: I attach different dimensions to brushes.

Answer (score 0):

How about two crossfilters built from the same records? The filtering one (`cfFilt`) would work as expected with dimensions for everything that can be filtered. The highlighting filter (`cfHigh`) would have one dimension (based on a record id or an identity function, `d=>d`) that is filtered by inclusion in `cfFilt.groupAll()`, plus dimensions that filter anything that can be highlighted. (`cfFilt().groupAll().reduce()` will need to return records, not counts. I can say how in comments if anyone needs to know.)

So `cfHigh.groupAll()` returns the records that pass through all the filtering and all the highlighting.

An interesting (and otherwise hard to achieve) consequence of this approach is that if you highlight something, then a filter makes that thing disappear, and then that filter is removed and the thing comes back, it will stay highlighted as long as nothing came along to change the highlighting filter in the meantime.